# Proving limit of multivariable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I want to prove that $$\lim_{x,y\to 0,6}\frac{8x+y}{x^2}=\infty.$$
I know the definition is
$$\forall E>0\quad\exists\delta>0:\left[\sqrt{x^2+(y-6)^2}<\delta\right]\Rightarrow\frac{8x+y}{x^2}>E.$$
I'm guessing the basic idea to proving that such a $\delta$ exists would be to evaluate $\frac{8x+y}{x^2}$ so that I can find a $\delta$ that is dependent on $E$. Unfortunately I don't have the slightest clue how to start doing that here.

Comment: $\frac {8x+y} {x^{2}} >\frac 8 x$ if $y>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noticed in the comments, since $y \to 6$, we have that eventually $5\le y \le7$ therefore

$$\frac{8x+y}{x^2}\ge \frac{0+5}{x^2}=\frac{5}{x^2}\to \infty$$